# Unable to retrieve value of JSON key using python

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am trying to import JSON data from an URL and extract the value of a specific key using python 2.7. I tried the following:

```
import urllib
import json
daily_stock = urllib.urlopen('http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/NFLX%3AUS?timeFrame=1_DAY')
stock_json = json.load(daily_stock)
print stock_json
```

The output is:

```
[{u'lastPrice': 95.9, u'lastUpdateDate': u'2016-04-22', u'price': [{u'value': 95.45, u'dateTime': u'2016-04-22T13:30:00Z'} ... 
u'dateTimeRanges': {u'start': u'2016-04-22T13:30:00Z', u'end': u'2016-04-22T20:30:00Z'}}]
```

When i try to retrieve the value of 'lastPrice':

```
print stock_json["lastPrice"]
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stock_json` is a *list* with a single dictionary inside, get the dictionary by index:

```
print stock_json[0]["lastPrice"]
```

Comment: Thanks! That works.Just an extension to the above question: When the json.load is used, dosen't it store as a dict by default? Why does it store as a dict within a list in this case?

Comment: @Harish glad to help. According to the [definition](http://www.json.org/), JSON object is built on 2 structures - an object/dictionary and a list/array. In this case, `json.load()` loads from a JSON array into a Python list..hope that helps.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks a lot for the clarification.